# What does "-?" as double type represent in C#?

Tags: c#, double

So I'm running iterations with this formula:
`double x = 10 / 0.25 * ((0.0002 * x1 * (10 - 0.25 * x1)) + 0.00217 * x2 * (20 - 0.25 * x2));` With this process: Xn+1 = f(Xn).
And if you start from negative X you will eventually end up with (-/+) infinity, so after 6 iterations I'm supposed to get infinity, but what I got surprised me and I couldn't find anywhere what that is, I got "-?", I've tried comparing it to +/- infinity and tried to compare it to int numbers just to clarify what it is, but I cant get anything out of it, for example, I've tried `if ("-?" > 1000) break;`, and it doesn't outcome as "true". Neither am I getting any errors by comparing it to int/double, I need to stop iterations when I start going into infinity, how can I do that?

code:

```
public static double CalculateX1(double x1, double x2)
{
    double x = 10 / 0.25 * ((0.0002 * x1 * (10 - 0.25 * x1)) + 0.00217 * x2 * (20 - 0.25 * x2));
    return x;
}

public static double CalculateX2(double x2, double x1)
{
    double y = 20 / 0.25 * ((0.00052 * x2 * (20 - 0.25 * x2)) + 0.0075 * x1 * (10 - 0.25 * x1));
    return y;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string writePath = @"C:\Users\evluc\Desktop\cord.txt";
    double X = -5;
    double Y = -5;
    int pointer = 1;
    double[,] coordinates = new double[10001, 2];
    coordinates[0, 0] = X;
    coordinates[0, 1] = Y;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        //double XTemp = CalculateX1(X, Y);
        //double YTemp = CalculateX2(Y, X);
        //X = CalculateX1(coordinates[pointer - 1, 0], coordinates[pointer - 1, 1]);
        //Y = CalculateX2(coordinates[pointer - 1, 1], coordinates[pointer - 1, 0]);            
        coordinates[pointer, 0] = CalculateX1(coordinates[pointer - 1, 0], coordinates[pointer - 1, 1]);
        coordinates[pointer, 1] = CalculateX2(coordinates[pointer - 1, 1], coordinates[pointer - 1, 0]);
        pointer++;
        if (Math.Abs(coordinates[pointer, 0]) > 1000 || Math.Abs(coordinates[pointer, 1]) > 1000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("infinity");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("X = " + coordinates[i, 0] + "," + "Y = " + coordinates[i, 1] + "; ");


    }
}
```

Comment: Why should `"-?"` be a double? IMHO it is a string.

Comment: Please, post a [mre]

Comment: Which output are u using? Just i`ve tried function...and seems it just writes "-∞" in console, maybe just ur console cant recognize this infinity sign?

Comment: Assuming `"-?"` represents a negative number, most likely `double.NegativeInfinity`, why should a negative number be larger than 1000 in this code you shared `if ("-?" > 1000) break;`

Comment: this is how I calculate x2, works same way as first formula, so that would be Xn+1 = f(X1n,X2n); Yn+1 = (X1n,X2n); formula for Y looks like this `double y = 20 / 0.25 * ((0.00052 * x2 * (20 - 0.25 * x2)) + 0.0075 * x1 * (10 - 0.25 * x1));` I'm printing it with Console.WriteLine(); during iteratins I keep each element in double[,] like this: double[0,0] = X, double[0,1] = Y; and the problem doesnt seem to be in the way im printing as i start comparing before printing anything

Comment: @RandRandom I'm taking the "-?" element with Math.Abs(); so I'm assuming my way of comparing must be correct

Comment: What is stopping you from sharing the complete code, would be so much easier to help, we all could throw it into our environment and debug it, 10 secs later you get an answer?

Comment: What do you see if you put `Console.WriteLine(double.NegativeInfinity);` at the start?

Comment: Your if doesnt trigger since you are increasing the `pointer` variable with `pointer++` between the assigmentment and the verification of the value. eg. you assign coordinates[15, 0] then increase 15 by 1 so you than have coordinates[16, 0] in the if condition

Comment: Move `pointer++` to the end of the `for` loop

Comment: see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFwB1.png

Comment: @RandRandom my gosh yes, thank u!

Comment: I removed your if block to get the output for all 5000 entries and have the following - https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0ehr.png a "-?" is no where to be found - notice I have added `|| X IsNegInfinity={double.IsNegativeInfinity(coordinates[i, 0])} |  X IsNegInfinity={double.IsNegativeInfinity(coordinates[i, 1])} | "` to the output, as the given answer already demonstrated you should use the static methods to very for infinity eg. `double.IsNegativeInfinity(d)`

Comment: since you have a variable declared `string writePath = @"C:\Users\evluc\Desktop\cord.txt";` - I am assuming you try to write the infinity symbole into a file but failed to declare the proper encoding that supports this symbol

Comment: @RandRandom yea I'm writing it all into txt to build attraction pool afterwards, but before that I  use ToString(); as i need to replace "," to dots in coordinates for matlab to work, so if you do that I think you will get -? tables in txt as I do, thanks again :)

Comment: For example if you were to write the output into the txt file that is encoded with ascii, you would get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyEdo.png

Answer (score 1):

I think whatever you use to display/inspect the value cannot print `∞`.

```
double d = double.MinValue;
d *= 2; 
Console.WriteLine($"{d}: IsInfinity: {double.IsNegativeInfinity(d)}");
```

```
-∞: IsInfinity: True
```

### Stopping at infinity

Here's a loop that stops at infinity:

```
double d = 2;
var i = 1;
while(!double.IsInfinity(d))
{
    d = i*d*d;
    i = -i;
}

Console.WriteLine(d);
```

```
-∞
```

Comment: I'm printing it with Console.WriteLine(); during iteratins I keep each element in double[,] like this: double[0,0] = X, double[0,1] = Y; and the problem doesnt seem to be in the way im printing as i start comparing before printing anything –